# How to add a Spring based RESTful service as Servlet to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am developing an application that uses a module-like approach. Several modules are loaded at runtime. One module is a Tomcat webserver and another is an implementation of a RESTful API that makes use of Spring.
I would like to add the whole Spring based RESTful API as a servlet to the Tomcat at runtime. Is this possible?

I have read about Spring Boot and it looks promising but I only find informations about creating a WAR file which I could deploy to the Tomcat. However, this is not possible because the RESTful API needs to be a module. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have some code to share with us?

Comment: @Abdelhak No sorry, its more a conceptual thought at this moment.

Comment: Spring uses a class called DispatcherServlet for all its http things. Did you try to do some [research](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=spring+rest+webservice)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create and configure the Tomcat Webserver

The webserver module runs the following code to create and configure
a Tomcat webserver.

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

// this defines Tomcat's working directory
File base = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
Context rootContext = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());

// more configuration ...
```

### Create and configure the Spring application context

The REST API module creates and configures a Spring application context as follows:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

context.register(SomeAnnotatedClass.class);
context.register(AnotherAnnotatedClass.class);

// more configuration ...

context.refresh();

// this is the servlet that we need to add to Tomcat
DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
```

### Deploy the Spring service with Tomcat

Now we put the things together and add the dispatcher servlet to Tomcat.

```
Context rootContext = getTomcatsRootContextFromSomewhere();
Servlet dispatcherServlet = getDispatcherServletFromSomewhere();

// add the dispatcher servlet to the root context
Tomcat.addServlet(rootContext, "mySpringService", dispatcherServlet);

// add a mapping to the dispatcher servlet
rootContext.addServletMapping("/api/*", "mySpringService");
```

I believe this is not the *best* solution because I am still a Spring/Tomcat noob. I would really appreciate tips and improvement ideas if you have some.

I hope that I was able to help someone with this special problem.